# count number entries for a log into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, logging

I have a database with log entries, like:

```
CREATE TABLE `cheaters` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `guid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `guid` (`guid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=973997 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Sample data:

```
mysql> select * from cheaters LIMIT 10;
+----+---------------------+-------+-------------------------------+
| id | date                | guid  | type                          |
+----+---------------------+-------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | 2011-12-15 18:16:16 | 17567 | Speed-Hack detected           |
|  2 | 2011-12-15 18:16:28 | 69460 | Speed-Hack detected           |
|  3 | 2011-12-15 18:16:29 | 82077 | Walk on Water - Hack detected |
|  4 | 2011-12-15 18:16:50 | 55710 | Speed-Hack detected           |
|  5 | 2011-12-15 18:16:50 | 84229 | Speed-Hack detected           |
|  6 | 2011-12-15 18:16:52 | 55848 | Speed-Hack detected           |
|  7 | 2011-12-15 18:16:53 | 48774 | Speed-Hack detected           |
|  8 | 2011-12-15 18:16:54 | 48774 | Speed-Hack detected           |
|  9 | 2011-12-15 18:16:56 | 48092 | Speed-Hack detected           |
| 10 | 2011-12-15 18:16:56 | 81389 | Speed-Hack detected           |
+----+---------------------+-------+-------------------------------+
```

I want to get some thing like:

```
+------------+---------------------+-------+
| DAY        | GUID                | COUNT |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
| 2011-12-15 | 17567               | 356   |
| 2011-12-15 | 69123               | 6     |
....                                    ....
| 2011-12-16 | 69123               | 8     |
....                                    ....
```

It is the number of entries per guid per day.
How can I get it? Which query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
date(`date`) as `day`,
guid,
count(*) as total
from cheaters
group by `day`,guid
```

**Updated answer.**

You have to add having clause at the bottom of your query.

```
select 
date(`date`) as `day`,
guid,
count(*) as total
from cheaters
group by `day`,guid
having total > X
```

Comment: Can I filter the result if the total is greater than X?